# Is it possible to change an xml to UTF-8 using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML document that is an ITF-16 LE Encoding. Because of that, It is not readable using wp all import.

When I look in the version section, I see this

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Unicode" ?>`
And in my visual studio code I at the bottom I see. 
`UTF-16 LE`

I already changed using Visual studio, but since it going to be a new file every time (in the same format). It would be great if PHP could transform it into UTF-8

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Unicode" ?>
<root>
  <docs>
```

Is it possible to change the encoding of this file using PHP?

Comment: [`mb_convert_encoding`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) might work

Comment: A simple XSLT with specified target encoding will do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOMDocument::loadXML()` reads the encoding attribute from the XML declaration. But `Unicode` is not a valid encoding *afaik* - I would expect `UTF-16LE`. The DOM API in PHP uses UTF-8. So it will decode anything to UTF-8 (depending on the defined encoding) and encode it depending on the encoding of the target document. You can just change it after loading.

Here is a demo:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo>ÄÖÜ</foo>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);

$encodings = ['ASCII', 'UTF-16', 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-16BE'];

foreach ($encodings as $encoding) {
    // set required encoding
    $document->encoding = $encoding;
    // save
    echo $encoding."\n".$document->saveXML()."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
ASCII
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<foo>&#196;&#214;&#220;</foo>

UTF-16
��<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<foo>���</foo>

UTF-16LE
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16LE"?>
<foo>���</foo>

UTF-16BE
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16BE"?>
<foo>���</foo>
```

The generated string changes with the defined encoding.

I started with an UTF-8 document here - because SO is UTF-8 itself and you can see the non-ascii characters that way. `ASCII` triggers the entity encoding for non-ascii characters. `UTF-16` adds a BOM to provide the byte order. SO can not display the UTF-16 encoded chars - so you get the � symbol. `UTF-16LE` and `UTF-16BE` define the byte order in the encoding, no BOM is needed.

Of course it works the same the other way around.

Comment: I think � in your apparent output is confusing and detracts from your answer. Surely, it is only an artifact of the way in which you are capturing the ouput and not a reflection of what would be written to an output file.

Comment: It is a *reflection* of what would be written to an output. It has to show broken characters because an UTF-8 page like SO can not display UTF-16 encoded characters.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic XSLT that will copy your entire input XML as-is, but with the encoding specified in the xsl:output. What is left is just to run an XSLT transformation in PHP.

> XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The XSLT is not needed here. It would require to load the XML into DOM (with ext/xsl) and if you do that you can just set the encoding property and save the document.